# AngularJS checkbox filter directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a AngularJS directive that allows users to select a values from a list to filter on.  Pretty simple concept which is represented here:

[image]

Problem is when I click one of the checkboxes they all select unintended.  My directive is pretty simple so I'm not sure why this is happening.  The code around the selection and checkboxes is as follows:

```
$scope.tempFilter = {
    id: ObjectId(),
    fieldId: $scope.available[0].id,
    filterType: 'contains'
};

$scope.toggleCheck = function (id) {

    var values = $scope.tempFilter.value;
    if (!values || !values.length) {
        values = $scope.tempFilter.value = [];
    }

    var idx = values.indexOf(id);
    if (idx === -1) {
        values.push(id);
    } else {
        values.splice(idx, 1);
    }
};

$scope.valuesListValues = function (id) {
    return $scope.available.find(function (f) {
        return f.id === id;
    }).values;
};
```

and the data resembles:

```
$scope.available = [{ 
     id: 23, 
     name: 'Store' 
     values: [ 
              { id: 124, name: "Kansas" }, 
              { id: 122, name: "Florida" }, ... ]
}, ...  ]
```

the view logic is as follows:

```
<ul class="list-box">
    <li ng-repeat="val in valuesListValues(tempFilter.fieldId)">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label ng-click="toggleCheck(val.id)">
                <input ng-checked="tempFilter.value.indexOf(val.id) === -1" 
                        type="checkbox"> {{val.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

First off, it `toggleCheck` fires twice but populates the correct data ( second time given my code it removes it though ).  [image]

After the second fire, it checks all boxes... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeat that I used to grab the values based on the id, was the problem area.

```
 <li ng-repeat="val in valuesListValues(tempFilter.fieldId)">
```

removing that and simple listening and setting a static variable resolved the problem.

```
 $scope.$watch('tempFilter.fieldId', function () {
     var fId = $scope.tempFilter.fieldId;
     if ($scope.isFieldType(fId, 'valuesList')) {
           $scope.valuesListValues = $scope.valuesListValues(fId);
                }
      }, true);
 });
```

and then in the view:

```
 ng-repeat="value in valuesListValues"
```

Comment: Heres a good directive with built-in support for checkboxes : http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its that the local variable doesn't get reassigned to the property of the scope property used in the view. Since your values are then non-existent and not found, the box is checked.

```
$scope.tempFilter.value = values
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the interface concept you were after and created a simpler solution. It uses a `checked` property, found in each item of `available[0].values`, as the checkbox model. At the top of the list is a button that clears the selected items.

**JavaScript:**

```
function DataMock($scope) {
    $scope.available = [{ 
        id: 23, 
        name: 'Store',
        values: [{
            id: 124,
            name: "Kansas"
        }, {
            id: 122,
            name: "Florida"
        }]
    }];
    $scope.clearSelection = function() {
        var values = $scope.available[0].values;
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i].checked = false;
        }
    };
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="DataMock">
    <ul class="list-box">
        <li>
            <button ng-click="clearSelection()">Clear Selection</button>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="val in available[0].values">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input ng-model="val.checked"
                           type="checkbox" /> {{val.name}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

[**Demo on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1784cMjcPmhigvjkdXJv?p=preview)

Comment: Appreciate the effort, however, my data structure does not permit it to be constructed like this, it is a very nice and clean solution though.  Thanks!